# changing link name with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I have taken over a Rails project and the CEO wants different link names that are currently shown on the webpage. I have very limited programming experience so I am having difficulty finding a clear answer on exactly how that is done. In a typical html page it is a very simple thing, but from the research it looks like you have to delete the current ones and recreate. Just trying to find an easier way to change what is displayed on the page. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You'll better making your post more specific, otherwise you'll get a lot of people asking you to close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Views**

> delete the current ones and recreate

Nope - you can just make any "HTML" you want. The trick is to appreciate that since Rails is an MVC framework, you'll need to be dealing with the `views` part of the application

[image]

The `views` are essentially the HTML files your application will use to display your content. Any `views` will be pure HTML mixed with `ERB` code - allowing you to locate & change the links you wish

If you only need to change HTML files, you *won't* need to "delete" the files and recreate them

--

**Links**

The links in Ruby on Rails, are applied with [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to "Your Link", link_path %>
```

This allows you to use as many links as you want, considering of course, you have the right link path & text for the link. This can be changed as you require... you don't need to use anything other than what I've listed above to get these working

Hope this helps!